# CSS is not proper of Org Chart (structured with ul and li)

Tags: html, css

I am creating an Org Chart using html and css but right side of chart is not properly formatted. Sales, Production1, Production2 should come under Joint Director, but it come below left side list. And right side connectors are also not properly connected.

My chart should look like this

```
                        Director
                             |
    (1)Joint Director(Account)               (2)Joint Director
                |                                 |
(1)Accountant1    (2)Accountant2     (1)Sales  (2)Production1 (3)Production3
                                          |
                                (1)Sales1  (2)Sales2  (3)Sales3
```

But its look like this:
https://smilestechno.000webhostapp.com/My/tree.html

**HTML**

```
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Director</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Joint Director(Account)</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Accountant 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Accountant 2</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Joint Director</a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sales</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Sales1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sales2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sales3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Production1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Production2</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>

        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.tree ul {
padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
float: left; text-align: center;
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
 }

 /*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
content: '';
position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
right: auto; left: 50%;
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

 /*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without any siblings*/
 .tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
display: none;
 }

 /*Remove space from the top of single children*/
 .tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

 /*Remove left connector from first child and right connector from last child*/
 .tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
border: 0 none;
 }
 /*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 }
 .tree li:first-child::after{
border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 }

 /*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
content: '';
position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding: 5px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #666;
font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
font-size: 11px;
display: inline-block;

border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;

transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
 }

 /*Time for some hover effects*/
 /*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code closing of li tag not placed proper structure. Use below code It works fine for me.

```
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Director</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Joint Director(Account)</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Accountant 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Accountant 2</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Joint Director</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sales</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Sales1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sales2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sales3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Production1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Production2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
            </ul>

        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: ohh its i a silly mistake. I closed Joint Director li so thats was a problem

Comment: but 1 little problem, i want main node in center. See its slightly going right side.

Comment: The main node is already in center based of total parent width but view wise it appear little bit right because your Joint Director block right is has sales content too. Due to use of 50% width for every li::before tag it made to appear miss align. You can over come this issue by making main node independent with position: absolute and give parent ul with position relative and align to center.

Comment: The code worked for me. Add a class to main node in HTML <a href="#" class="mainNode">Director</a> and add CSS lines in file .mainNode{
  position: absolute;
  left: 39%;
  bottom: 100%;
}
.mainNode::after{
      content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 23px;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0;
    height: 20px;
}
.mainNode + ul::before{
  display: none;
}

Comment: thats work. N now i am trying to horizontally center entire graph in page but it is not aligning to center.

Comment: .tree class add the following css to make it center .tree{ width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; }

Comment: Its looks perfect now. Thanxx

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have another ul as child of a ul. Correct structure is

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> Answer

```
 ...
 <li><a href="#">Joint Director</a> <!-- remove </li> here -->
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Sales</a> <!-- good here -->
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Sales1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Sales2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Sales3</a></li>
             </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Production1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Production2</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li> <!-- add </li> here -->
   ...
```

> Snipplet

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.tree { 
  width: 100%; height: auto; display: flex; justify-content: center;
}

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  float: left; text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

 /*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
  right: auto; left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
  border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
  border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Director</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Joint Director(Account)</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Accountant 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Accountant 2</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Joint Director</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sales</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Sales1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sales2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sales3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Production1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Production2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
            </ul>

        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: love the answer. Is there a way to set overflow-x to scroll. Not sure where to add it. I ve got a long list of children..